# Pattern for working with a form in Silverlight 4? (How to get references to XAML elements)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have a form:

```
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding Editable, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"
                                ToolTipService.ToolTip="Add new topic to this group">
                        <sdk:AutoCompleteBox Width="160" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.TopicNames}" />
                        <Button Click="addTopicButton_Click">
                            <Image Source="Images/appbar.add.rest.png" />
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
```

This form appears in a `DataTemplate` for an `ItemsControl`. I'm not sure what the best way is to get the data from the `AutoCompleteBox` when the button is clicked. I can't give the elements `x:Name` attributes, because they're in a template (right?).

How can I get around this? The `Click` event will give me the `Button`, but I need a reference to the text box. Use the Button's parent, then look through the children for the Textbox? If I factored this out into its own `UserControl`, I could set `x:Name` values, but I'd rather not do that.

Any other ideas?

**Update**: Here is another example of such a problem:

```
                    <ListBox x:Name="topicList" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Id, Converter={StaticResource topicGroupIDConverter}}" 
                             SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                               Width="150"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Description}"
                                               ToolTipService.Placement="Right" />

                                    <Button ToolTipService.ToolTip="Remove this topic from this group" 
                                            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=topicList, 
                                                                 Path=DataContext.Editable, 
                                                                 Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"
                                            Click="removeTopicButton_Click"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            Margin="10,0">
                                        <Image Source="Images/appbar.cancel.rest.png" />
                                    </Button>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

When the button is clicked, I want to access `topicList.DataContext`. However, `topicList` itself is a `DataTemplate` in an `ItemsControl`, so I can't access it using its name from code-behind. How else can I do this?

Comment: i did a minor edit to remove the `Silverlight 4` as a tag from your title and integrate it more naturally into the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property, say `SelectedItemInAutoCompleteBox`, to your presenter, and then can bind it to the `SelectedItem` property of `AutoCompleteBox`, using `Mode=TwoWay`, like this,

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedItemInAutoCompleteBox, Mode=TwoWay}"  ... />
```

You may try the same approach with `Text` property of `AutoCompleteBox`, also. See if it solves your problem.:-)

Comment: right, but if the `AutoCompleteBox` is in a data template in an `ItemsControl`, and there are multiple items, which one will bind to the data context?

Comment: @Rosarch : if by multiple items you meant "TopicNames", then no, you don't need to bind to any of them, all you need to do what I said, `SelectedItemInAutoCompleteBox` will be used to store the value which you've selected, that is why I wrote `Mode=TwoWay`, so that once you select one item in the autocompletebox, this item will be stored in `SelectedItemInAutoCompleteBox` which you can see from your presenter. Try doing it.

Comment: @Rosarch : and if I misunderstood you somewhere, then please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have several choices:

1. If you're on Silverlight 5, use the AncestorBinding
2. Otherwise, use a [Silverlight 4 AncestorBinding hack](http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/) (it doesn't look pretty)
3. Or you could try [DataContextProxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx), which stores the DataContext in a resource so that it is accessible.  Note: you should set the DataContextProxy as a Resource of topicList ListBox, not the UserControl as in Dan Wahlin's example.